# How to display routing error like as JSON in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

When I call underined route in URL I get Laravel error as HTML page:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
```

How I can replace this on JSON format response?

Answer (score 2):

You can create JSON response in `app\Exceptions\Handler.php@render()` method:

```
if ($e instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors#render-method